# Drupal form submission to another page

Tags: forms

Below is my form and form submission function. The form is displayed in page-front.tpl.php. Using this code i could print $_POST variable in the front page. But i would like to submit to some other page say page-result.tpl.php. How could i do that without using $_session variables

```
    function q_search_form($form_state) {

$form['category'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array('' => 'Any', 2 => 'Automotive', 1 => 'Real Estate'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'drop-box'),
    '#prefix' => '<table width="470"><tr><td width="170">Select Category</td><td width="300">',
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr>'
);
$form['city'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array('' => 'Any', 'kozhikode' => 'Kozhikode', 'kochi' => 'Kochi'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'drop-box'),
    '#prefix' => '<tr><td width="170">City</td><td width="300">',
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr>'
);
$form['property'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array('' => 'Any', 18 => 'Land and House', 17 => 'Land'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'drop-box'),
    '#prefix' => '<tr><td width="170">Property</td><td width="300">',
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr>'
);
$form['wanto'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array('' => 'Any', 'sell' => 'Sell', 'buy' => 'Buy'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'drop-box'),
    '#prefix' => '<tr><td width="170">Want to</td><td width="300">',
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr>'
);
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Search'),
    '#attributes' => array('id' => 'Search', 'class' => 'srch-button'),
    '#prefix' => '<tr><td><a class="adv-srch" href="#">Advance Search</a></td><td>',
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr></table>'
);


return $form;
}


  function q_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $wantto = $form_state['values']['wanto'];
    $property = $form_state['values']['property'];
    $city = $form_state['values']['city'];
    $category = $form_state['values']['category'];

    $sql = ' SELECT A.nid FROM node A 
        LEFT JOIN content_type_item B ON A.vid = B.vid
        LEFT JOIN term_node C ON A.vid = C.vid
        LEFT JOIN term_hierarchy D ON D.tid = C.tid
        WHERE A.type = "item" 
        AND B.field_tr_type_value = "'.$wantto.'"
        AND B.field_city_value = "'.$city.'"
        AND D.parent = '.$category.'
        AND C.tid = '.$property.'
      ';
   $result = db_query($sql);   
  while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
     $output['srch_result_nid'][] = $row['nid'];
    }


  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `form_submit`, add `$form_state['redirect'] = <your_url>`, at the end.

Comment: If i use $form_state['redirect'] $_POST values wont be available in the new url

Comment: you could allocate the value in some other global variable and unset the variable after use.

Answer (score 0):

This is the multi-step form problem. Try http://drupal.org/project/mforms

You end up with the data stashed into an array on each step.